# google drive sample code is showing jackson2 package does not exist java compile time error

Tags: java, ubuntu, gradle, google-drive-api

I've configured GDrive API from following tutorial to ubuntu cloud hosting.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java

configurations are in following screenshot.
[image]

It's showing " package com.google.api.client.json.jackson2 does not exist" error
[image]

though i tried to add that jar file to lib directory but that didn't fix the issue.
[image]

with that i've also added following files
[image]

please advice, thanks

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, where text would do.  We can not search in
or copy from screenshots.

Comment: Sure, I'll keep that in mind.